# Including C++ headers, "..." vs. <...> style, official ISO/IEC opinion?

Tags: c++, include, iso

I know, this is an old question that has been asked many times [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename). I agree with the common answer that `#include <filename>` should be used for system headers and `#include "filename"` should be used for project-local headers.

However, now I found [this paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1204r0.html) from the ISO/IEC C++ Tools Working Group, which states the following:

> All headers within a project should be included using the `<>` style inclusion and contain the project name as a directory prefix. And all headers means all headers public, private, or implementation detail, in executables or in libraries.

They also give an explanation:

> The problem with the `""` style inclusion is if the header is not found relative to the including file, most implementations will continue looking for it in the include search paths, the same as for `<>`. As a result, if the header is not present in the right place (for example, because it was mistakenly not listed as to be installed), chances are that a completely unrelated header with the same name will be found and included. Needless to say, debugging situations like these is unpleasant.

I don't understand this. Why does this problem not occur with the `<>` style?

Bonus question: What's the status of such a paper anyway? Can it be considered an official recommendation of the ISO/IEC C++ consortium, peer-reviewed and acknowledged by many experts? Or is it just a proposal by someone in order to trigger a discussion?

Comment: "*Can it be considered an official recommendation of the ISO/IEC C++ consortium, peer-reviewed and acknowledged by many experts?*" No. Until it becomes an actual ISO standard or Technical Specification, it's just a proposal.

Comment: As far as I understand, it says *`""` is bad, because it does precisely the same thing as `<>`*. Also, this paper is basically just a bunch of opinions - "I like this convention, why is not everyone using it"?

Comment: I recommend refraining from placing path names into the source file.  If the header files move, then the source needs changing.  Prefer to supply the path names to the compiler.

Comment: I prefer placing path names into the source files.  If the header is moved, the compiler will notify the user.  For me, any search that finds 'the missing header' has a chance to also find any other header files of the same name.  On a large system I worked on, there were 5 copies of doo.hpp (3 different versions), providing a 80% chance I modified the wrong one on my first try, despite being in the 'dominant' version.  I prefer 'relative path's.

Comment: I would like `#include >header.hpp<` which would exclude searching the standard locations if not found in the project specific locations :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood. The author of the paper suggests to use only include paths that are specified with the `-I` flag to the compiler, but not to use any relative search paths. This makes sense if the relative include path is always given in the `#include` statement, and only one `-I` flag needs to be given for the root of the project.

Anyway, it is a highly interesting paper that quite changed my understanding of how to structure C++ components. I'd wish to see more like this from the committee.